# how to change data-offset-top property in css

Tags: html, affix

Does anyone know I can change the data-offset-top property in css? I set data-offset-top="-150" in the HTML document, but I would like to change that in a @media statement in css, since the offset changes for mobile devices.

Comment: using bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1024px)').matches){
            $('.test').affix({offset: {top: 150} });
        }else{
           $('.test').affix({offset: {top: 250} }); 
        }
    }).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: thanks, but I am looking for a css solution rather than javascript

Comment: @carl can you give me fiddle? maybe i can help you

you try give your affix block padding-top?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the `data-offset-top` property in CSS, because it is **not** a CSS property. It is an HTML attribute of Bootstrap's `affix` that you're trying to use.

If you want a CSS solution, the closest you could do something like -

```
<div class="desktop-only" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="160">
<div class="mobile-only" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="change_to_whatever">
```

and then in your CSS, hide these respective classes at appropriate resolutions -

```
.mobile-only{
    display : none;
}

@media your_media_query_for_smaller_devices{
  .mobile_only{
     display : block;
  }
  .desktop-only{
     display : none;
  }
}
```